# How to get current location using googleapiClient then put marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-api-client

I do want to get current location with GoogleApiClient with this code below,

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if(mLastLocation != null)
    {
        currentLat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        currentLon = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot get lat and lon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

then after that i do want to put marker on current location, my problem is mLastlocation still null

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    dGoogleMap = googleMap;

    if(mLastLocation != null)
    {
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(currentLat, currentLon))
                .title("My Current Location");

        dGoogleMap.addMarker(marker);
        dGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(currentLat, currentLon), 16));
    }
}
```

Or this is my fault missunderstand the flow of async, or just my poor logic needs to be improved.

Comment: Do you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> or <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> permissions in your manifest? and also enabled location in the phone that you are testing

Comment: i already put those in my android manifest and also enabled location in my phone. didnt work out

Comment: Are you testing it on marshmellow?

Comment: nope i testing it on lolipop sir @ShashankUdupa

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36396029/2032561

Answer (score 0):

Put below line in your `onMapReady` method

```
dGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```